# How to use batch-import of neo4j

Tags: maven, csv, neo4j

I'm totally new of neo4j and maven.

I'm using a [batch-import](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) tool to convert my mysql to neo4j.
After compiling and converting from .csv, a target file containing graph.db is generated.
Does it mean that I have successfully converted my .csv into neo4j?
What should I do now?

Hope there is someone who can help me.

Comment: Oh, I roughly understand. I should first install the neo4j server on ubuntu and link the path to the target pointing to graph.db

Comment: You can either copy your `target/graph.db` to your `/path/to/server/data/graph.db` or you can edit `conf/neo4j-server.properties` to specify the full path to your created db as store-location. But move it somewhere else as the target directory will be cleaned whenever you run `mvn clean`

Comment: Make sure that the server is not running when you replace the graph.db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options to inspect your converted data.

**Java REST server**

Download and [install](http://www.neo4j.org/download) the Neo4j server. Connect to it via `http://localhost:7474`. Launch a cypher query to inspect your data. E.g. `START n=node(*) RETURN n;`.

**Java embedded server**

You could write a small java application that connects to your data directory. E.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("db");       
    final ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
    System.out.println(engine.execute("START n=node(*) RETURN n").dumpToString());
    graphDb.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice reply. I've started my server. Neo4j is amazing.